# How do I know how long I am banned for suggesting edits?

Tags: discussion, editing

One of my edit was rejected then I got banned for suggesting edits. I would like to know when this ban will be removed.

All I got was this:

[image]

It doesn't tell me how long it would be. Are you sure the feature of this site really tells me the time period?

Comment: You had more then a single edit rejected.  When you attempt to perform an edit it should indicate how long the ban is.  I know when you are banned from flagging a question/answer it tells you.  You should update your question to include how many edit suggestions actually were rejected.

Answer (score 5):

Your ban will expire in 23 hours from now so approximately 18:00 04 March 2016.

In future though, please do more than just edit titles. The edits you have been doing were superfluous at best and in at least one case actively harmful.

[This edit in particular](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/504642) was completely wrong as it changed the product being queried from MSSQL to MySQL.  The original was correct, though uncapitalised, while your edit was useless (correcting case) *and* bad.

Comment: And what about the reviewers who **approved** that bad edit?

Comment: It is weird. I cannot see my previously rejected edits in "all activities".

Comment: Is there a way to know this time myself?

Comment: I suspect that only moderators can see your ban time, so the best way is to ask here or in the [Ask a Super User Moderator](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator) chat room.  I *thought* I had left you a comment when I rolled back your edit above, but apparently not.  My comment still stands though, edits should be ***substantive*** improvements to the post, not just fixing capitalisation in the title.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I suspect this particular edit ban involved moderator intervention..  I can't see the user's edit history, which is the reason I asked for it, if he had more then a couple rejected edits it would explain the edit ban.  *It sounds like the multiple trivial edits caught the eye of somebody which was then reported though*

Comment: @Mokubai I would also like to know how long my edit ban is set to last for.